# how to create infinite /continous mesh in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, mesh

I was thinking how to crate the infinite three mesh as seen in this game ?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjDp21_X0SU

Is it a one big mesh or dynamically generate as the game progress ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not "infinite mesh" in OpenGL.

You may do that using two cylinders: When one cylinder is at back, away from the camera view, you translate it to the front of the "actual" cylinder.